# How to control what the open with Disambiguation dialog shows?

Tags: android

Is there a way to control what is shown in a Disambiguation dialog(aka open with) and only show 2-3 predefined apps?

So i can get a clean small bottom sheet like the one in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot control the native dialog.

You can use deep-links to trigger that window and depending on the deep-link it will show specific category apps